# Annoying Fn keys

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I'm trying to put my laptop on fullscreen mode with <kbd>F11</kbd>, but I don't hold in the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at the same time, it only mutes my laptop, and it's really annoying! I know it's possible to change it, but I can't find out how.

I've looked everywhere, but nothing helps.

I'm using a Windows 8 Toshiba.

I'm not sure about the other details. I guess that "SATELLITE C850D-11F" might help?

Comment: How do you know it's possible to change it? Maybe there's some way to enable "Fn Lock" (like Caps Lock etc.), but I haven't heard of a laptop where you can change it permanently yet.

Comment: @gronostaj You can usually change it permamently in BIOS. Works almost always

Answer (score 1):

Usually making the F-keys work as F-keys require changing a BIOS setting, as described in these questions:

- [How can I make my laptop F-key's work as F-keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/590417/how-can-i-make-my-laptop-f-keys-work-as-f-keys?rq=1)
- [How To Permanently Lock the "Fn" Key Down So It Is Active On My Laptop Keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/235796/how-to-permanently-lock-the-fn-key-down-so-it-is-active-on-my-laptop-keyboard?rq=1)

But apparently, at least on some Toshiba notebooks, you can change the F-keys' behaviour directly in Windows, as is described in this Toshiba help article: http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD2503B90001R01.htm, and on this website: http://www.ejeindustries.com/support/ToshibaFunctionKeys.html

In case those sites ever go down, here is the screenshot of the Toshiba help article:

[image]

You would need to select "Standard F1-F12 mode" in the category "Function Keys mode".